# Android Studio: execSQL(String sql) do not throw SQLException

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

On the documentation it say's 
**execSQL(String sql)  Throws: SQLException - if the SQL string is invalid**

but it do not in android studio, any one having this problem ?

```
public class test extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 public test(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);     
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
      db.execSQL("some sql code");
     }
    catch(SQLException e){
      //do something            
    }       
  }
 //some other overrides
}
```

This will give me error an error because  execSQL() is not throwing an exception.when checking its declaration  I get

```
public void execSQL(String sql)  {
  executeSql(sql, null);
}
```

So my question is in the documentation and even on eclipse I am sure it returns a SQLException but here on Android Studio its not.

Comment: I think he is talking about the documentation. Can be it the case?

Comment: What exactly happens? Is the exception handler really empty?

Comment: Hey guys my problem is not about the code, but according to the documentation it should return that exception. even if you check it on eclips this i can catch the  SQLException. So I am just asking if it is only on my Android studio or every one's

Comment: Did you import `java.sql.SQLException` or `android.database.SQLException`?

Answer (score 4):

`execSQL()` can throw `android.database.SQLException`. If you inadvertently imported `java.sql.SQLException` as first suggested by Android Studio, you'll get an error

> Exception 'java.sql.SQLException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block

To fix it, import `android.database.SQLException` instead.